# How to reference System.Windows namespace in .Net Core?

Tags: wpf, .net-core, wpf-core

I'm a long time WPF (.Net Framework) developer finally dipping my toes into .Net Core for the first time. I'm currently trying to convert a small v4.7.2 WPF application to .Net Core 3.1. The solution contains a WPF app project and a class library project, with only a handful of classes each, so I decided it would be easier to create a new solution containing a WPF app and class library project (both .Net Core 3.1), then copy the cs and xaml files from the original solution. However I seem to be falling at the first hurdle...

Many of the classes use types from the `System.Windows` namespace (and `System.Windows.Media`, `System.Windows.Controls`, etc). These resolve fine in the WPF app project but not the class library. I've noticed the WPF app project has a reference to the framework "Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Wpf", but the class library project doesn't, which I assume is my problem. However I can't for the life of me figure out how to add this framework into the project. How do I do it?!

I've seen solutions elsewhere of adding `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` to the class lib csproj file, but this has no effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As usual, no sooner do I post the question than I find the answer. I also had to change the SDK in the csproj file to:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
```